# Email from trigger not going

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger which sends email but some how the email is never received. There is no error in the debug logs.

Here is my code

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailM = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String[] listOfRecipients = new List<String>();
        listOfRecipients.add('***********@gmail.com');

        emailM.setToAddresses(listOfRecipients);
        emailM.setTargetObjectId(contId);
        emailM.setWhatId(guId);
        emailM.setPlainTextBody('Test email');
        emailM.setorgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailId);


        try {

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {emailM});

            return;
        }
        catch (EmailException e)
        {
            system.debug('Error in sending email');
        }
```

Update

Answer to this question:
I had set the email deliverability to All Emails, and its done.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: No Exception in the debug logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the email address is valid one and Access Level is **All Emails** under Deliverability settings

```
Setup->Administer->Email Administration->Deliverability
```

in your org.